# CanvasJS Dynamic Div

Tags: javascript, canvas, promise, canvasjs

An issue has arisen whilst I've been using CanvasJS. It seems the div that the chart will be rendered in needs to be present before creating the chart.

Is there a way around this as once my function returns the charts, I wish to add the needed chart divs to the body and then render the charts. Our current code is like this:

```
charts(limit).then(function(res) {
  for (key in res) {
    var thiselem = document.getElementById(res[key].options.chart.container);
    if(!thiselem) {
      thiselem = document.createElement("div");
      thiselem.id = res[key].options.chart.container;
      thiselem.style.height = "33vH";
      thiselem.style.width = "100%";
      document.body.appendChild(thiselem);
    }
    res[key].render();
  }
}, function(err){console.error(err);});
```

However it fails at the first .render() with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can assign dynamically created DIV to chart. Please refer this example.

```js
var chartsOptions = [{        
 data: [
 {
  type: "column",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 71 },
   { x: 20, y: 55 },
   { x: 30, y: 50 },
   { x: 40, y: 65 },
   { x: 50, y: 95 },
   { x: 60, y: 68 },
   { x: 70, y: 28 },
   { x: 80, y: 34 },
   { x: 90, y: 14 }
  ]
 }     
 ]
},{        
 data: [
 {
  type: "column",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 71 },
   { x: 20, y: 55 },
   { x: 30, y: 50 },
   { x: 40, y: 65 },
   { x: 50, y: 95 },
   { x: 60, y: 68 },
   { x: 70, y: 28 },
   { x: 80, y: 34 },
   { x: 90, y: 14 }
  ]
 }     
 ]
}];

var charts = [];
for(var i in  chartsOptions){
 charts[i] = new CanvasJS.Chart(assignDiv(chartsOptions[i]), chartsOptions[i]);
 charts[i].render();
}


function assignDiv(options){
 if(!options.chartContainer){
  var thiselem = document.createElement("div");
      thiselem.id = "ChartContainer" + (charts.length + 1);
      thiselem.style.height = "33vH";
      thiselem.style.width = "100%";
      document.body.appendChild(thiselem);
      options.chartContainer = thiselem.id;
   }
   return options.chartContainer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```